# Unwanted quotes exception in String in Python

Tags: python, string, exception

Lets say I want to print exactly this: `text \" text2`.

The best output I can take is: `text " text2`.

Is there any way to put the above text in a string exactly as it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> print(r'text \" text2')
text \" text2
```

Comment: `r""" whatever """` will also allow you to have new-lines in the quote

Comment: I'd suggest using `print()` in answers since we don't know which python version the OP is using.

Answer (score 3):

A backslash is used to write special characters, such as newline (`\n`), and to escape (undo special meaning of) another character following it. In this case, you're escaping the `"`, which is sometimes necessary when it might mean the start or end of a `string`:

```
print "string with \" in it" # string with " in it
```

If you want a backslash as it is, use the raw string notation as shown by @jamylak, or escape the backslash by placing another backslash in front of it:

```
print 'text \\" text2' # text \" text2
```